# Scroll to top inside an iframe when clicked

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have an iframe which pops up on click event on the main page. The iframe has a big form content, so when I click on a reset botton at the end of the form I want the iframe content to scroll to Top.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#reset").click(function (e) {  
        /*clearFormContent();*/ 
        $('body').prop('scrollTop', 0);
    }).click(function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I have tried the above code but not working for me, I have tried, `.animate({scrollTop:0})` too
But it doesn't seem to work. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to fix the issue:

```
  $("#reset").click(function (e) {  
                                 $('html, body').animate({
                                     scrollTop: $("body").offset().top
                                       }, 500);
                                }).click(function (e) { e.preventDefault();});
```

Comment: inorder to make this to work on ie7, replace the body selector with the html, like scrollTop: $("html")

Answer (score 1):

then try to detect onload event and do it that way:

```
var myIframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
myIframe.onload = function () {
    myIframe.contentWindow.scrollTo(xcoord,ycoord);
}
```

Comment: if your iframes content is from a different domain than the domain that is hosting the main pages content, you will not be able to do this due to cross domain scripting regulations.

Comment: You are right but at least I should be able to make it work locally right?

Comment: if by locally you mean both the page src and iframe src are localhost, then yes.

Comment: are you suggesting to create a name function for onload event and call the same function on click event? Because I want to scroll when i click on reset button inside the iframe itself. bzw the iframe is a popup created by onclock event on the main page. The behavior is not working for IE not for chrome.

Answer (score 0):

change your code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#reset").click(function (e) {  
        /*clearFormContent();*/ 
        $('body').prop('scrollTop', 0);
    }).click(function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

for this

```
$(function(){

        $("#reset").click(function (e) {  

            $(this).parents("body").animate({scrollTop:0});
        }).click(function (e) { 
            e.preventDefault();
        });

})
```

Comment: the reset button is inside the iframe and i want the iframe content to scroll to top when i click that button.

Comment: Fisseha Should be working make sure the iframe has imported the jquery, Open the browser console and check for errors

Comment: iframeId is an example, you should put the id of your iframe.

Comment: yes, actually i used mine, its just for our conversation i keep using "iframeid". I can get the body.html() content but i can't get the iframe itself.

Comment: This is not working on IE but its working on Chrome though(my first attempt - $('body').prop('scrollTop', 0) - also works on chrome too)